# Making AJAX call without holding / intercepting page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, logic

What's the best way of requesting data via / through AJAX without holding progress of other assets / resources being loaded on the page. The issue being the fact that the returned data / information from your AJAX call is needed .e.g returned data will be used to populate / generate your HTML page.

Practical example:

```
$.get("pageURI", {getVar:getVal}, function( data ){
   var response = data;
});
```

1. You could wrap your code with $(document),ready(function(){}); and generate HTML when document is ready, but again, without surrounding your page generation logic within the AJAX call, thus inside $.get(...)..., how do you make sure that the page only gets populated with your content accordingly only when you know that response has the expected data, thus !undefined.
2. I do not have an issue with code being inside the AJAX call wrapper, but what if you have a lot of code that's dependent on the response , in other words you have about 10 - 15 long functions and other logic, is it advisable to have them wrapped around your AJAX call ?
3. I also understand that one could set response as a window property (window.response) / global variable and only use it once page has fully loaded e.g $(window).bind("load", function(){}), as it might be used in various places throughout the program lifecycle, but is that good coding practice ?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't follow. AJAX calls are asynchronous and don't hold up page loading or rendering.

Comment: Hi Wainage, my question might not be clear and sorry for that, but what I mean, as I have stated repeatedly and I think quite explicitly on parts of my question, if you look at my code snippet, you'll see that there is response being set to data inside the $.get function, if you try to use that variable (response ) outside your call, you will get undefined and not the expected value.... that is my problem...

Comment: There's no way around that ... you have to wait for that to become available since AJAX calls need time. Update your page from within that callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought there could be another way outside my knowledge of AJAX... I personally do not like wrapping a lot of logic / code around $.get/post(...). Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the minimal page, as needed, and execute the Ajax call.  jQuery gives you a nice callback to execute when the Ajax call is complete, and you can use that to kick off the other functions that are dependent on it.  Consider this:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "/twiddle-bits", function(data, status, jqXHR) {
  // Here is where you call functions that do the second-stage data population
  apply_changes_after_ajax_call();
  update_some_other_things();
})
.fail(function() {
  show_error_messages();
});
```

This should do what you're looking for.  The HTML page will be rendered prior to the Ajax call, and you can update the DOM once you have the results back.  That's how it works with dynamic pages like this.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am aware of the idea you are suggesting, I wanted to know if there were other ways around that, but I probably overthought and reached a point where I believed there could be better ways around that.

Thanks

Comment: @HlawuM The only other way is to implement synchronous rendering, and you'd want to do that on the server.  Using Ajax explicitly says that you want asynchronous rending on the client, so you have to pick which approach fits your situation.

Comment: I would not say it did / did not, as I highlighted on the first comment, What you wrote is what i already knew, I was looking for something different, if there is. Thanks for your answer and follow up.